# Focus remains on textbox on tabbing in Google Chrome browser

Tags: c#, javascript, google-chrome

I am faced with this peculiar problem that happens only for the Google Chrome browser.

For any textbox which has a required field validator, if I enter some values and tab out of it, it works fine.

However, if the value is removed (the content is totally deleted) and  tab out of the textbox, or click on another textbox, for the first time the focus remains on the textbox.

How can I solve this issue? It works fine on all other browsers.

An example of a textbox would be:-

```
<asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="SwiftCode" meta:resourcekey="SwiftCodeLabel"/><span class="required">*</span>
<asp:TextBox id="SwiftCode" runat="server" CssClass="field-input account-detail"/>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" EnableClientScript="True" ValidationGroup="BankDetails" ControlToValidate="SwiftCode" ID="SwiftCodeValidator" SetFocusOnError="True" meta:resourcekey="SwiftOrRoutingValidator"  CssClass="validation-always-hide" />
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ValidationGroup="BankDetails" EnableClientScript="True" ControlToValidate="SwiftCode" ID="SwiftCodeCustomValidator" ClientValidationFunction="bankAccount.isSwiftCodeValid" SetFocusOnError="True" meta:resourcekey="SwiftCodeCustomValidator"  CssClass="validation-always-hide" />
<span class="hint bank-details-hint"><a href="https://news.customhouse.com/faq/spp/?q=53" target="_blank"><%=GetLocalResourceString("SWIFTBIC")%></a> <%=GetLocalResourceString("SWIFTBICHint")%></span>
```

Now the bankAccount.isSwiftCodeValid is a simple jQuery function that goes like this:-

```
function isSwiftCodeValid(source, args) {
        var isAlphaNumeric = /^[a-z0-9]+$/i;
        args.IsValid = (args.Value.length === 8 || args.Value.length === 11) && isAlphaNumeric.exec(args.Value);
    }
```

Comment: show some code, or it did not happen.

Comment: this is still not enough code, please post the jquery code that references the function.